Typing gets obstructed by pop up menu
I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 (minimal installation, without internet) as a dual boot along with Windows 11 on a single drive. Whenever I am going to type things, the pop-menu showing copy paste select, etc." is showing up obstructing my typing.

Besides random actions are happening while typing. For example, new terminals are being opened automatically stopping typing, text is being selected and deleted automatically and while typing on gedit, opening the emoji panel, etc.
I got this error message during the file system check of the installation process. "Error found in 1 file. You might encounter an error.
I couldn't find any relevant resources on this topic. So I reinstalled it getting the same error message. But this time, it is a Normal installation with an internet connection for updates and additional drivers for wifi, graphics, etc. But the same problem occurred again.
Please suggest what might be the cause and approach to solve this issue.
